# Image to fit to div size and make clickable

Tags: html, css

First post here, I've read the guidlines so I hope I'm asking correctly.

I've been trying to get an image to fit to a div but what happens is it fits in the div but doesn't stretch to it's size.

The other thing I've been trying to do is to make that image clickable.

Is there a way to do that calling the image from css?

Here's what I've been trying.

```css
#container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  max-width: 80%;
  height: 500px;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #000000;
  border-top: 50px solid #000000;
}

#container img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="images/slider.jpg" alt="design"  />
</div>
```

Also should I be using id and # or class and . ?

Comment: why do not you set the background in css.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having one single `#container` serving the purpose of `contain`ing the elements, should be fine. I have updated the way you have to ask the question. That's fine too. And for your situation, may be you should remove the `border`.

```css
#container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  /*border-bottom: 50px solid #000000;
  border-top: 50px solid #000000;*/
}

#container img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="design" onclick="alert('Hi, you have clicked!');" />
</div>
```

Comment: @codeRomeos I tried to do that using this: background:url(../images/slider.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px; I couldn't get it to work though :(

Comment: Thank you very much that's awesome!

Comment: @Garrus If this helps, please click on the tick next to my answer to mark it as accepted one.

Comment: That does help but what i asked was for the image to stretch to the size of the container. I appreciated the help :)

Comment: @Garrus The image is indeed stretching to the size of container. What exactly would you like to happen here.

Comment: @Garrus Have a look at the updated answer, see if it works for you.

Comment: @Praceen-Kumar very sorry about that. My mistake. The image i tried was the wrong version. If i want to make the image open a link when clicked would this work? <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="design" a href: "index.html></a>

Comment: Actually I figured that out. I just put <a href=""> before the img src. Thanks very much :)